# Using data-slide-to and javascript to add a class to carousel navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey so I've build a carousel and carousel nav using bootstrap. Now I want to be able to detect the value of 'data-slide-to' and apply a style to the corresponding navigation item based on that value.

Carousel Navigation

```
<div class="carouselNav">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <ul>
      <li><a class="" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide-to="0">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <h3>Web Design</h3>
      </a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide-to="1">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <h3>SEO</h3>
      </a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide-to="2">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <h3>Project Management</h3>
      </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- col -->
    </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container -->
```

Proposed Javascript (where #web would be a unique ID given to each nav item)

```
    if (data-slide-to.value == 0) {
    $('#web').addClass('highlight');
} else {
    $('#web').removeClass('highlight');
}
});
```

Proposed CSS

```
.highlight {
}
.hightlight::after {
content: ' >';}
```

Essentially the Navigation would have an '>' after it when the corresponding slide (0,1,2) was active. Any direction would help.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery .data to work with data attributes

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Thanks for the reply -- I wasn't able to see how this connects but I appreciate the effort. Cheers.

Comment: Well that part was to retrieve the value of the "data-slide-to" attribute. So what exactly are you having trouble accomplishing? You seems to have the basics in place.

Comment: Id like to be able to detect the value of 'data-slide-to' and add a CSS class to an element depending on the value. I think that value is the .data you're talking about but I'm not sure how to connect it.

Comment: It depends on how you want to set up the nav and carousel, but you might not need to use your data-slide-to attribute. Those numbers are the same as the index of the parent li elements of your links, so you could just use that.  Here is a demo I made for another question on stack overflow and it might be useful to you as far as understanding how to put something like this together.  http://jsfiddle.net/troythompson/57b49y20/